# Proving function in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous if for every $x \in \mathbb R$ and every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that

$$|f(y)−f(x)|< \varepsilon \ \ \text{whenver} \ \ \ |y−x|< \delta$$

(a) Show that the function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by

$$f(x) = 4x − 3$$

is continuous.

I am revising for my exam and I am unable to arrive at the answer. Does anyone know how I can tackle this.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [MSE quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide more context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: So you took an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Then you formed $|f(y)-f(x)|=4|y-x|$. What kept you from finding an appropriate $\delta$?

Comment: also note, at least from how I've learned analysis, this is uniform continuity not general continuity at a point

Comment: @julien: Oops!  Never mind.

Comment: @DanZimm No. This is continuity at every $x$. Not [uniform continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity). The $\delta$ depends on $x$ as it comes after.

Comment: @julien the definition of continuity at a point $x_0$ is that $lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$. This is the definition of uniform continuity. Nowhere does he say this $\delta$ depends on $x$ so I believe that it's safe to say, since he wrote the definition of uniform continuity that it doesn't depend on $x$. Surely that wikipedia article is comparing continuity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) and uniform continuity. If you're arguing that he says "for every x", then I'd say, nowhere does he say "for every y"... also note that continuity is a local property, not a global one

Comment: @DanZimm No. This is not uniform continuity. Uniform continuity would be: for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ (to copy the OP's phrasing). It would be maybe better to say: such that for all $x$ and $y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Here, the $\delta$ only depends on $\epsilon$. It is uniform. In the definition of continuity (which is the one given by the OP), the $\delta$ arrives after the $x$, which is why it depends on $x$. There is no need to "say" it. It is a fact due to quatifiers.

Comment: @julien I suppose I am unfamiliar with this "quantifiers" business (clearly I'm ignorant of it :P) so I apologize - none the less this seems a bit convoluted, at least in my mind

Comment: @julien also, put your first comment in an answer, I'm guessing the OP will then close this

Comment: @DanZimm Yes, I think you are misleaded by the quantifiers. The $\lim f(x)=f(x_0)$ without quantification characterization is more "early calculus" oriented. Because it relates to: the function is continuous if I can draw the graph in one shot. But continuous functions can be monstruous: check the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). For more subtle cases, the quantifiers are actually a great help and it is not that hard to get used to them. It just takes some practice.

Comment: @julien yea, so I'm used to the epsilon delta characterization, meaning given $\epsilon > 0 \; \exists \; \delta > 0$ s.t. $\lvert x - x_0 \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(x_0) \rvert < \epsilon$ tells us that $f$ is continuous at $x=x_0$, which is a local property - but the OP's characterization seems to imply that continuity is a global property. But yea I understand now how this is a local property, but being applied to an interval of points

Comment: @DanZimm Exactly. It is like continuity at $x_0$, like you said. But for every $x_0$, which comes at the beginning of the whole sentence: $\forall x_0 \;\forall \epsilon>0\;\exists \delta>0$...

Comment: @julien ya, so exactly as you said, the quantifiers tripped me up, thank you very much for enlightening me!

Comment: @DanZimm You're welcome. I'm glad we understood each other.

Comment: You can show that it is differentiable, which is a stronger statement.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x) = 4x - 3$.

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ be arbitrary, we want to show that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose $\displaystyle \delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$, if $\vert x - x_0 \vert < \delta$, then $$\vert f(x) - f(x_0) \vert = \vert (4x - 3) - (4x_0 - 3) \vert = 4 \vert x - x_0 \vert < 4 \delta = 4 \frac{\varepsilon}{4} = \varepsilon. $$

---

Usually, the way I think through these problems is: I let $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta = \boxed{\text{to pick later}}$, then I go about my calculations, adding restraints on $\delta$ as I go along to make the proof work out. Then I go back and fill it in with the appropriate value.